# java Minio Server exception: “The specified key does not exist”

Tags: java

I am using the Minio server 3.0.6 in an java using a getObject request to download an image from my minio server bucket.

i am geting the following error
error occured
ErrorResponse(code=NoSuchKey, message=The specified key does not exist., bucketName=null, objectName=null, resource=/resourse-server/284/health/1509086845373.doc, requestId=3L137, hostId=3L137)
request={method=GET, url=http://hostname:portnumber/resourse-server/284/health/1509086845373.doc, headers=Range: bytes=0-
Host: hostname:portnumber
User-Agent: Minio (amd64; amd64) minio-java/dev
x-amz-content-sha256: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
x-amz-date: 20171028T063134Z
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=*REDACTED*/20171028/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;range;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=*REDACTED*
}
response={code=404, headers=Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/xml
Server: Minio/RELEASE.2017-07-24T18-27-35Z (linux; amd64)
Vary: Origin
X-Amz-Request-Id: 14F1A834C5D82B02
Date: Sat, 28 Oct 2017 06:31:34 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
}